# Will Simmering Help/Harm Pumpkin soup?

Tags: soup, pumpkin

I am making cream of pumpkin soup. 
I need to go do the weeks shopping and also get the cream I forgot. (Cream is added in the last step of my recipie)

The recipie I am using calls for it to be cooked for about 20 minutes,
but shopping will take about an hour.

For many soups simmering them for 1 hours vs 20 minutes, is an enhancement that lets the flavor come out.

Is pumpkin soup one of them?

Comment: Are you making it from a can?

Comment: If you are making it from scratch, simmering the ingredients (as long as you have an appropriate amount of moisture) should heighten or increase the aromatic qualities of the soup.  You've heard the phrase "time is money"... well in soup development "time is flavor." IMO

Comment: @Chef_Code: I've never heard of making it from a can. I though you just put canned pumpkin soup in a microwave an ate it.
I'm doing it the normal way of boiling pumpkins (etc) then blending them. (This particular recipie doesn't call for roasting them first).

Comment: overcooked pumpkin tastes tinny or is it just me?

Comment: I believe Chef_Code means tinned pumpkin puree, not soup. From what I understand, pumpkin is much more popular in the US than in other countries and pumpkin pies generally call for canned, cooked pumpkin.